# Why can I not load Image through Javascript in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I need to load an image to get its dimensions (so that I can adjust the SVG `viewbox` properties I'm using it in). After I migrated to Nuxt.js from Vue, I get an error saying 
`ReferenceError Image is not defined` for this line:

```js
this.image = new Image() // <= this line gives the error
var vm = this;
this.image.onload = function(){
    vm.width = this.width;
    vm.height = this.height;
}
this.image.src = this.photo.url;
```

I Don't really understand why there is no `Image` on `node.js` so can't work around the problem. Is there a solution to this that doesn't require 3rd party libraries?

Comment: use `mounted` instead of `created` as `mounted` doesn't run in SSR

Comment: That works. Forgot about the difference between `created` and `mounted`.